# cant url encode colon ":" when calling twitter api to create post

Tags: api, twitter, httprequest, twitterapi-python

Im trying to create a tweet but it looks like it fails when there is a colon, in this case `hello:`:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello: this would have been a cool tweet
```

I also tried percent encoding using `%3A` but twitter continues to give me a `401`. When removing the colon, it works fine.

Any idea? I'm eventually trying to tweet a timestamp like `May 01, 2021 12:07:21`

Answer (score 0):

Using `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` solved my problem